# Streaming Songs as Alarms on my Nexus One to Bluetooth Speakers

Tags: bluetooth, alarm, mp3, bluetooth-audio

I know there are several apps available that allow the user to utilize .mp3 files/songs as an alarm.  So when the alarm is triggered, the selected song/playlist starts to play.  I'm also aware that if one connects his/her android device to an external speaker via a 3.5mm audio jack, the audio will be sent to the speaker for output.  I'd like to do this using a set of bluetooth speakers.  How can I stream the audio from my NexusOne to my bluetooth speakers so the alarm song automatically plays through my speakers rather than through the output on my phone?

Will the bluetooth coupling between the devices remain paired throughout the night?  Is this functionality dependent on the app I'm using or on the type of bluetooth speakers (or both)?

Thanks in advance for any help!  Its truly appreciated! :)